# FK or FPK? Relational Databases

Tags: mysql, database, relational

I have question that I can't find anywhere on the internet answer for.
It's about database design.

What is the difference between FPK and FK?
I know PK.

But I don't uderstand fully idea of FK/FPK keys, whenever we have FK or FPK.

Comment: There is no "FPK". What do you mean by it? What do you think a "FK" is? What is a reference textbook you are using? PS See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you you refer to Foreign Keys and Primary Keys.
Here is an interesting article that explains Keys:
https://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-the-difference-between-a-primary-key-and-a-foreign-key/

A Foreign Primary Key can be used when you have a table that is related 1:1 but dows not have related records for every record in the main table.

Example:
Lets say you have a table T1 with information and you have unique information records for some records but not all in T1.

So you decide to store the data in another table T2 in order to not have columns with hundreds of empty cells.

As these are unique records (1:1 between T1 and T2) T2 can either have an own primary key and a foreign key or combine them into 1 field using the foreign key as primary id (T2.T1_id):

```
CREATE TABLE `T1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `T2` (
  `T1_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `specinfo` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`T1_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `t2_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`T1_id`) REFERENCES `T1` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: I still doesn't get fully the idea of Foreign Primary Key :/

Answer (score 0):

There is no "FPK" (foreign primary key?). What do you mean by it? Why do you think there is one? What do you mean by "FK" (foreign key) then? What academic (organization/person) textbook are you using?

In the relational model (but not SQL): A superkey is a set of columns with unique values. (SQL `UNIQUE NOT NULL` column set.) A CK (candidate key) is a superkey that contains no smaller superkey. A PK is some CK you decide to call the PK. A FK references any CK, not just a PK (primary key). It says a subrow value for a column list must appear as a subrow value for a CK column list somewhere else.

In SQL: A `FK` declaration declares a *foreign superkey*, ie it references a superkey, ie an SQL `UNIQUE NOT NULL` column list. It's only *actually* declaring a FK when the superkey it references is actually a CK (possibly the PK), ie is actually a superkey that contains no smaller superkey, ie is a `UNIQUE NOT NULL` or `PK` that contains no smaller `UNIQUE NOT NULL` or `PK`.